# Type for constant referencing its own values

Tags: typescript

given I have this array:

```
const rooms: Rooms = [
    {name: 'bathroom', neighboring: []},
    {name: 'kitchen', neighboring: ['living room']},
    {name: 'living room', neighboring: ['kitchen']},
] as const;
```

I'd like to write a type for `Rooms`, which only allows values in the `neighboring` array which are also values of the `name` property.

I tried it like this:

```
type Rooms = Array<{
    name: string,
    neighboring: RoomName[]
}>

type RoomName = typeof rooms[number]['name'];
```

Unfortunally this causes an TypeScript error:

> The type 'readonly [{ readonly name: "bathroom"; readonly neighboring: readonly []; }, ...]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'Rooms'.

Do you have a better idea?

Comment: The error you report is not related to what you ask in the question. Remove `as const` from the definition of `room` and the error disappears. If you need to declare it `as const` they you have to make `Rooms` and all the types involved in its definition read-only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a generic type for your rooms array, and a helper function to infer the type parameter from the actual array.

This is using the `NoInfer` type from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67374694/12299000) so that the room names are inferred from the `name` property, and then only type-checked in the `neighboring` property (so if you put a wrong room name in `neighboring`, you'll get an error, which is desirable).

```
type RoomsArray<K extends string> = Array<{name: K, neighboring: NoInfer<K>[]}>

function makeRooms<K extends string>(rooms: RoomsArray<K>): RoomsArray<K> {
    return rooms;
}

const rooms = makeRooms([
    {name: 'bathroom', neighboring: []},
    {name: 'kitchen', neighboring: ['living room']},
    {name: 'living room', neighboring: ['kitchen']},
]);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gSQHYDMICcA8AVAfFAXigG1sBdUqCAD2AiQBMBnKAQyRCgH4oAGKAFxQkEAG4YyAKEmhIUAEpw4AWyYBBdOlYhMAaSq16zKE2DoAlkgDm+Ihq06A3klbKIQ3QBphEc1YAWAEZwFtZC8MhoWLq4xGQAvrjSKACuSADGwOZwSFDKrADWEIoqTHoGdIwspqE2ABToSqpCJar22nq4AJQtTeqaHTFQjpJQY1DoEMAp6LmNpQDckvHS6TmmE32EeYXFfXXEo+POru5QAOSBrMD+88rn3iJ+QSGWVkJx8Z5HYyduQucCuZgOl-PQHj5nsFah9zgAbcyiN6bFTnBLfcbDFz-C4IpHWFH3R6+ALQt6woEgsFINFfSRkLpLIA)

Answer (score 0):

Can extract room name into its own type?

```
type RoomName = string;

type Rooms = Array<{
    name: RoomName,
    neighboring: Array<RoomName>
}>
```

Can also constrain the room name into specific strings:

```
type RoomName = "bathroom" | "kitchen" | "living room";

type Rooms = Array<{
    name: RoomName,
    neighboring: Array<RoomName>
}>
```

Here's a [TS playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9nAtgOQIaOgXigIgEarAAWATgojlAD64DWAlsAMZEQB2lNOANvQG702AcyhkkOANwAoKaEixyAZyjYAgiRKoQAHgDeUqIaht0EAFwKkaDABoDRthHpCieOCUFCL6zTvhXTAD4pAF9gqSY4NkVgUSULf0RlbABte0NdEwwLAHICYjFEHJtjJxc3D2ELFIBdELsjKEzTXIZmVjZi0udXd09qnN4BYTikHLqGo2bsqEH%20T1Giksceiv6oFJy2lnZx%20qkamUjo2MLFAHVGIgBRDXcEpRUN9Kas81n80nIulfK%20qo2Exe03eW0YO06yzKvUqXg2OTYcFiqEWe0mGTeuURyNRUNW-zhm22HTRByAA):

[image]

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing as a workaround, but I think it's dirty to have to define every room name twice.

Comment: @user3817008 why twice?

Comment: Yeah, it's only defined once?

Comment: @VLAZ One time as type and one time in the array as value

Comment: It's a type in both cases plus that's exactly what you want no? You want one field to be a room name and another an array of room names? Not sure what you mean by "dirty" in this situation

Comment: @user3817008 then how do you expect to link them? You cannot do it without 1. Naming the thing 2. saying where a link points to. Doesn't matter how you define the links you need *at least* two references. Unless you define them as a tree structure but that is also restrictive as it won't allow you a bathroom linked to a kitchen that is also linked to a living room. Or similar. You also straight up cannot have circular links with that.

Comment: @VLAZ If you think of it as a graph, then of course you have to write both the nodes and the edges in order to fully describe the graph - the issue with this answer is that it writes the nodes twice (once in a union type declaration, once in the array), in addition to listing the edges. It's possible to avoid that repetition so that you just write the nodes once (and the edges once, of course).

Answer (score -1):

There is (or there should be) a short and known list of room types. Put them in an `enum` then use the `enum` to define more complex types:

```js
enum RoomName { 
    bathroom = 'bathroom', 
    kitchen = 'kitchen',
    living = 'living room',
};
type Room = {
    name: RoomName,
    neighboring: RoomName[],
};
type Rooms = Room[];

const rooms: Rooms = [
    { name: RoomName.bathroom, neighboring: [] },
    { name: RoomName.kitchen, neighboring: [RoomName.living] },
    { name: RoomName.living, neighboring: [RoomName.kitchen] },
];
```

Check it [online](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBASg9nCA5AhhYUDeUCwAoKQqAIxQBcALAJwWgF4oByUymxRgGlwKIGsBLMgGMKoKA0YDhokJ3xEoAG34A3fiADm4psrWaobCHLwBfANz4yATwAOGeIm2Z5REGmAAuWLVToOLwhBgfg0KYjgqdQ0vB2R3AG0AXX9TCzxrO29EAGdtWKS0-CE4EGyyA1psmMrteICsKDd0asRfYAA6FmpaLiCQsIiorySoExSFbCbPLLj0dqkRUF7g0PDIzWHYtvbdKMTR8aJJ9xbZjt3NZf61oah4rfd5wUWQfbH8RMK8IA).