# Typescript infer vs generics

Tags: typescript

I noticed that we can do this:

```js
//type MyType<T> = T extends infer R ? R : never;
type MyType<T> = T

type T1 = MyType<{ b: string; }> // T1 is { b: string; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typescript/3.2.2/typescript.min.js"></script>
```

Also both `MyType` have the same result, so my question is: What is the difference between these 2 types?

Comment: There is no difference in what values are assignable to the types, they are both identity operations, or "do-nothing" operations. There might be some differences in some edge cases due to conditional types being resolved later than other types.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In that case, there is a difference when `T` is a union type, the former will give `{x: Foo} | {x: Bar}` whereas the latter will give `{x: Foo | Bar}`. Again, those are the same type in terms of what values are assignable to them, but they'll behave differently in some circumstances, and the edge cases are different to the edge cases for the original example.

Comment: Thanks @kaya3! Note to self: Never forget about conditional distribution of union types!

Comment: @kaya3 - Actually, I wonder if that might be the basis for an answer here. As you can tell, I certainly didn't think of it (despite having been exposed to that information at least three times). I'm still at an early journeyman level with TypeScript, but then...so are many others. :-D So it might be helpful to folks.

Comment: It might be, but for this specific example, distributivity doesn't have any effects and so any differences in behaviour are likely to be caused by how resolution of conditional types is deferred in some cases (e.g. like how `[T][T extends any ? 0 : never]` is value-set equivalent to `T` but [behaves differently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67374694/12299000) with type inference). But it's not clear if the OP is actually interested in these identity-operations or if the example code is over-simplified from their actual use-case - so I await clarification.

Comment: @​AskMen - Is your question about the behavior of identity types, or about the behavior of conditional types using `infer`?

Comment: This is sort of like asking about the difference between two 10-dollar bills and one 20-dollar bill.  For most purposes there is no difference, and although I can start trying to imagine situations where there is a difference, it's probably better to find out from you what you're planning to do with the money before I waste my time and energy envisioning wacky scenarios.  So... what are you going to do with `MyType<T>`?